# what is the error in my code for NQueens problem?

Tags: c++, c++11, n-queens

```
    vector<vector<string>> ans;
    void addtoans(vector<vector<int>> &board, int n){
        vector<string> row;
        string s = "";
        int i,j;
        for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
            for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
                if(board[i][j] == 1)
                    s = s + 'Q';
                else
                    s = s + '.';
            }
            row.push_back(s);
            s = "";
        }
        ans.push_back(row);
        return;

    }
    bool issafe(vector<vector<int>> &board, int row, int col, int n){
        int i,j;
        for(i = 0;i < row;i++)
            if(board[i][col] == 1)
                return false;
        int x = row, y = col;
        while(x >= 0 && y >= 0){
            if(board[x][y] == 1)
                return false;
            x--; y--;
        }
        x = row; y = col;
        while(x >= 0 && y < n){
            if(board[x][y] = 1)
                return false;
            x--; y++;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool solveNqueen(vector<vector<int>> &board, int i,int n){
        if(i == n)
            return true;
        int j;
        for(j = 0;j < n;j++){
            if(issafe(board,i,j,n)){
                board[i][j] = 1;
                bool nextqueenpos = solveNqueen(board, i+1, n);
                if(nextqueenpos)
                    return true;
                board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    vector<vector<string>> solveNQueens(int n) {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0;i < n;i++){
            vector<vector<int>>board(n,vector<int>(n,0));
            board[0][i] = 1;
            bool ispossible = solveNqueen(board,1,n);
            if(ispossible){
                addtoans(board,n);
            }

        }
        return ans;
    }
```

NQueens problem : The n-queens puzzle is the problem of placing n queens on an n×n chessboard such that no two queens attack each other. 
This is the piece of code i have written on leetcode. My output is [] which is wrong. my code is returning blank vector. Please help me find the error in code.

Comment: `if(board[x][y] = 1)` sets the board position and evaluates to true (because it is non-zero).  Is that intentional?

Comment: Hey thanks Eljay. This was the problem you pointed out. Now the code is working fine.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. Modern compilers can warn against stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to imagine the exact question input and output type but, assuming the position of the first queen is (x=0, y=0) you can place the next queen at (x=x+1, y=y+2) or (x=x+2, y=y+1). You stop if your x or y values are larger than n.